# How to block certain protocols with ipset?

Tags: ubuntu, iptables, routing, ipset

The thing is, I currently have 3 virtual test machines, **Client1**, ip `192.168.1.10`, **Client2**, ip `192.168.2.20` and **Router** with ip `192.168.1.1` and `192.168.2.1` as gateway to connect Client1 and Client2.

On **Router**, I have `hash:ip,port` set, for example:
`ipset add myset 192.168.2.20,tcp:80`
`ipset add myset 192.168.2.20,tcp:443`

On **Client2** I have nginx setup to listen on port 80, and I don't want **Client1** to be able to connect to **Client2** via tcp on port 80, on **Router** I add a rule: `iptables -A FORWARD -m set --match-set myset dst -j DROP`

On **Client1** I exec `wget 192.168.2.20/index.html` and due to my iptables rules on **Router**, **Client1** shouldn't be able to connect to **Client2** and grab `index.html`, however, it doesn't work and file can be successfully retrieved.

The problem is only with `hash:ip,port` set type of ipset. If I choose `hash:ip` type and move protocol/port part to iptables out of ipset, everything works fine. However, I need to use exactly ipset to be able to swap block lists any time.

What am I doing wrong? All 3 VMs are running on Ubuntu 17.04, minimal installation, no GUI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/200518/how-to-match-properly-against-an-ip-set-of-type-haship-port#comment431657_200518) comment, the problem is solved:
Instead of
`iptables -A FORWARD -m set --match-set myset dst -j DROP`
I had to use
`iptables -A FORWARD -m set --match-set myset dst,dst -j DROP` (two **dst** instead of one)